# Rails 3 create a link to image_url and show image_url(:medium)

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox

I am trying to create a link to an image `@user.image_url`. This will be the full sized image. I want the medium resized image to be shown `@user.image_url(:medium)`. But what I also want is for the `@user.image_url` to open in FancyBox.

My current code at the moment is:

`<%= link_to image_tag @user.image_url(:medium), :style => "width:717px;height:409px" %>`

This links to the Users profile page, which is what I don't want.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets for nesting methods

```
<%= link_to image_tag( @user.image_url(:medium), :style => "width:717px;height:409px"), @user.image_url %>
```

Comment: Just got it working with this  `<%= link_to image_tag(@user.image_url(:medium), :style => "width:717px;height:409px"), @user.image_url %>` - Thanks anyway